Ubuntu + Cinnamon Alt-Tab window switcher icons+preview: make selected window more obvious?
I use Alt-Tab to switch between windows with "icons and window preview" for the "Alt-Tab switcher style" setting.
The previews indicate the selected window by slightly graying over the non-selected previews.  I'm finding that if I have several light-ish windows (say, a terminal and text editor both with dark text on light background) I have to really study them to discern which window is not grayed out - that is, it's really hard for me to identify the selected window at a glance.
Is there a setting to adjust the color or alpha for graying over such that the switcher makes the non-selected windows much more different from the selected window?  I'd like it to be obvious to me at a glance which window is selected, and right now it's not.
Ubuntu 22.04/Cinnamon 5.2.7
